# "No such kernel named python3" ipywidgets/ipykernel dependency issue

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dependencies, ipywidgets

I was confronted with a strange failure message in a CI process which had been working a few weeks ago:

```
jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named python3
```

What recent (Aug 2023) change might cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

After a fair bit of research, I determined that there was a design change in ipywidgets (see https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3731) to remove ipykernel as an explicit dependency. If you encounter this error message, it is worth checking whether you have been relying on the old ipywidgets dependency to bring in ipykernel. The change appears to be official/permanent as of ipywidgets>=8.1.

Since I was unable to find any other StackOverflow messages describing the issue, I thought that writing it up might be helpful to others.